# surface.Bake(); no such command

Tags: unity, navmesh

Regarding the code [shown in this video at 13:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-RXnDGE72M%E2%88%88dex=12&list=PL4AZfZ_v6LZNn6LPUbYFyKJNlssdzlu9K):

When I try: `surface = GetComponent (); surface.Bake()`;

I am getting the following error message:

> UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshSurface does not contain a definition for bake
> and no extension method Bake of type UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshSurface
> could not be found "are you missing an assembly reference

I am struggling to get the dynamic navmesh working with Unity 2017.1.

Comment: Are you sure you updated Unity to 5.6?

Comment: I am working with 2017.2, this is the next version after 5.6

Comment: These aren't built in yet, https://github.com/UnityTechnologies/NavMesh-Feature-Demo